# How can I alter the primary key of an index-organized table?

Tags: oracle

We started with a naive primary key:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE books(
        title VARCHAR2(10),
        CONSTRAINT pk_title PRIMARY KEY(title))
      ORGANIZATION INDEX;

Table created.
```

Then realized it is not unique. Say, a book can be re-released under the same title:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE books ADD(release_date DATE NOT NULL);

Table altered.
```

Now to insert a re-released book, we have to relax the uniqueness on title somehow.

But I cannot drop and recreate the PK due to the table being index organized:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE books DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE books DROP PRIMARY KEY
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-25188: cannot drop/disable/defer the primary key constraint for
index-organized tables or sorted hash cluster
```

I cannot manage to extend the existing key in-place either:

```
SQL> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pk_title_date ON books(title, release_date);

Index created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE books MODIFY PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX pk_title_date;
ALTER TABLE books MODIFY PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX pk_title_date
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14196: Specified index cannot be used to enforce the constraint.
```

What are my options ? Is it possible without moving data or recreating the table (the actual table is huge) ?

Comment: I think you're out of luck there (I don't think even dbms_redef can do this), but would love to be proven wrong. (The "alter table primary key" trick has no chance of working on an IOT, it's not an in-place modification at all for an IOT.)

Comment: "naive" primary key?  roflmao  (I know it's a typo - still can't help chuckling at the thought ) (I wonder if it's any different than a non-intelligent key? O.o )

Comment: It's not a typo but 'm not English speaker so it could be wrong. I meant that assumptions were made about uniqueness, that turned out to be wrong (after a long time and the need for new features).

Answer (score 2):

An index-organized table (IOT) is just that; an index with no "real" table.  All data besides the primary key are just "tacked on" to the primary key, so for example if you have an IOT with 6 columns, 2 of which make up the primary key, behind the scenes you just have an index with 6 columns, of which the first 2 columns make it unique.

So, sorry, only way to fix it is to recreate the table; to improve the rebuild time temporarily disable logging.  You cannot use an `append` hint on inserts to an  IOT table to force a direct path insert:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE books_new (
    title VARCHAR2(10),
    release_date DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_title PRIMARY KEY(title,release_date))
  ORGANIZATION INDEX NOLOGGING;

SQL> INSERT INTO books_new 
     (SELECT title, '01-Jan-1980' FROM books);
SQL> ALTER TABLE books_new LOGGING;
SQL> ALTER TABLE books RENAME TO books_old;
SQL> ALTER TABLE books_new RENAME TO books;
```

Comment: `'01-Jan-1980'` is a character literal, not a date and relies on implicit data type conversion to the `DATE` data type. Don't do that. Use explicit date literals. Either `to_date('01-Jan-1980', 'dd-mon-yyyy')` which is subject to the client's NLS settings. Or better a standard ANSI SQL literal: `date '1980-01-01'`

Comment: Yeah, I was being lazy.  Glad you made that clear for people who don't know better. :)